# Alfa Romeo Spider ( soft top ) been n storage almost 12 years

Tags: long-term-storage

I have the above car stored in Spain in a dry garage. It has been there almost 12 years.   The car is of great sentimental value to me, and would love to get it up and running again.  The car was in perfect condition when I drove it from the UK to Spain.Only reason it was stored was because to put it on Spanish plates at the time was going to cost me a huge amount of money ( Spanish tax ! )
I have read much here about similar stories re car storage, and I am hoping that due to the fact that my car has been stored well ( dry and out of the sun ) it may not be too difficult a job. I cant bear the thought of never driving it again :(  I sincerely hope I am not kidding myself, but seriously want to bite the bullet and try !!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it has been stored in a dry garage bodes well - that should have kept the dreaded rust away! It should also have stopped mould from getting into the interior...

Have a read through the other long term storage questions here, which should give you a few tips.

You will need to replace the battery, tyres and all the rubber hoses - brake lines, coolant hoses etc. I'd also replace the brake pads and discs, and the cam belt if it has one.

Drain and refill the oil, remove the spark plugs and dribble a small amount of oil down the plug holes. Leave it overnight, then try to turn the engine over by hand - use a spanner or socket on the crankshaft. If you are lucky it won't have siezed! If it does turn freely you can try replacing the plugs and trying to start it. Otherwise the engine will probably need rebuilding.

The clutch may well have siezed too - they can be freed off using some fairly agricultural methods...

Gearboxes are usually fine, but will probably benefit from an oil change - the same with the differential.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, give the soft top some love. Hopefully it's been stored in the upright position. Clean it and put some conditioner on it before you take it back outside. Otherwise it stands a good chance of cracking the first time you take it down.

Comment: You may find the wheel bearings have suffered - may be fine, but need checking...